# Google Cloud SQL No Response

Tags: mysql, sails.js, google-compute-engine, waterline, google-cloud-sql

We are running a Sails.js API on Google Container Engine with a Cloud SQL database and recently we've been finding some of our endpoints have been stalling, never sending a response.

I had a health check monitoring /v1/status and it registered 100% uptime when I had the following simple response;

```
status: function( req, res ){
    res.ok('Welcome to the API');       
}
```

As soon as we added a database query, the endpoint started timing out. It doesn't happen all the time, but seemingly at random intervals, sometimes for hours on end. This is what we have changed the query to;

```
status: function( req, res ){
    Email.findOne({ value: "someone@example.com" }).then(function( email ){
        res.ok('Welcome to the API');
    }).fail(function(err){
        res.serverError(err);
    });
}
```

Rather suspiciously, this all works fine in our staging and development environments, ***it's only when the code is deployed in production*** that the timeout occurs and ***it only occurs some of the time***. The only thing that changes between staging and production is the database we are connecting to and the load on the server.

As I mentioned earlier we are using [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction) and the [Sails-MySQL](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql) adapter. We have the following error stacks from the production server;

```
AdapterError: Invalid connection name specified
at getConnectionObject (/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:1182:35)
at spawnConnection (/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:1097:7)
at Object.module.exports.adapter.find (/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:801:16)
at module.exports.find (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/dql.js:120:13)
at module.exports.findOne (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/dql.js:163:10)
at _runOperation (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:408:29)
at run (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:69:8)
at bound.module.exports.findOne (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/basic.js:78:16)
at bound [as findOne] (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
at Deferred.exec (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js:501:16)
at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
at ret (eval at <anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promisify.js:163:12), <anonymous>:13:39)
at Deferred.toPromise (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js:510:61)
at Deferred.then (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred.js:521:15)
at Strategy._verify (/app/api/services/passport.js:31:7)
at Strategy.authenticate (/app/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:90:12)
at attempt (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:341:16)
at authenticate (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:342:7)
at Object.AuthController.login (/app/api/controllers/AuthController.js:119:5)
at bound (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
at callbacks (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
```

---

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error : 
Could not connect to MySQL: Error: Pool is closed.
at afterwards (/app/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:72:13)
at /app/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:40:7
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

Looking at the errors alone, I'd be tempted to say that we have something misconfigured. But the fact that it works some of the time (and has previously been working fine!) leads me to believe that there's some other black magic at work here. Our Cloud SQL instance is D0 (though we've tried upping the size to D4) and our activation policy is "Always On".

EDIT: I had seen others complain about Google Cloud SQL eg. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31434829/2601584) and I was suspicious but we have since moved our database to Amazon RDS and we are still seeing the same issues, so it must be a problem with sails and the mysql adapter.

This issue is leading to hours of downtime a day, we need it resolved, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [sails issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2309), and not necessarily related to Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thanks Nick! We up and moved the entire database to Amazon RDS as a test but we still see the same issues. As you say, must be sails, though that issue is quite old. It may be the same thing, at least we have something to test now!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way the QPS limit for Google Cloud SQL is being reached? See here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps

Comment: In the link it explains that there is no QPS limit but rather a maximum concurrent connections limit. We are using a D0 instance which has a limit of 250 concurrent connections, the most we have ever used is 12. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

Why is my database instance sometimes slow to respond?
In order to minimize the amount you are charged for instances on per use billing plans, by default your instance becomes passive if it is not accessed for 15 minutes. The next time it is accessed there will be a short delay while it is activated. You can change this behavior by configuring the activation policy of the instance. For an example, see Editing an Instance Using the Cloud SDK.

It might be related to your policy setting. If you set it to ON_DEMAND, the instance will sleep to save your budget so that the first query to activate the instance is slow. This might cause the timeout.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no we use the "Always On" activation policy, I will add this information to my question.