# Postgresql slow simple queries using PHP PDO/driver

Tags: php, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Having a hard time understanding why PostgreSQL from google cloud services is taking > 400 ms for any simple query (~4-row table) from my PHP code using PDO or pg driver. IP ping averages around 60 ms so it seems it's not a distance problem. Using both PGAdmin and PHP yield around a 400+ ms response time.

```
$before_conn1 = microtime(true);
$result = pg_query($connector->conn(),$query);
$after_conn1 = microtime(true);

$test = $after_conn1 - $before_conn1;
echo $test;return;
```

// response time 0.46275 unix timestamp

query looks like this:

`SELECT id,clearance from table`

literally the table has 4 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: What is the time for `select 123;` query? Also, maybe you should edit and post your exact query here, but change names (to prevent security leak).

Comment: @Top-Master, thanks for the prompt response. Select 123 took 0.4780

Comment: Then it seems to be an intentional limitation (from Google side), maybe see [another post about this same matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54503560/8740349)

Comment: What is $connector->conn() doing? Does it make a fresh connection? If so, do you use a connection pool?

Comment: Maybe try again and exclude the time of `$connector->conn()` method (by storing it's result in a variable, before `$before_conn1 = ...` line).

Comment: @FrankHeikens the conn() uses a normal pg_connect call:

public function conn(){

  $password = "x";
  $user = "x";
  return pg_connect("x dbname=x user = $user password = $password");

 }

and also I have a PDO connection setup: 
   $password = "x";
   $user = "x";
            $this->connection = new PDO("pgsql:host=x;dbname=x;user = $user;password = $password");

both yield same response time.

Comment: First, don't create a new connection for each query, just do it once and reuse that connection. But second, and most important, start using a connection pool.

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks for the observation , I'm using the same variable to query to avoid opening new uneeded connections. Not sure if connection pool work with PHP but I will definitely read more about it. On the other hand Im testing on a single query PHP file and through pgadmin which yield the same response time of ~ 0.5 secs per query "select 123" :/ I'm a bit desperate since this is for a custom ERP website Im developing and requires several back and forth requests to the DB and the wait time can be up to 10 secs for each employee info request...

Answer (score 1):

Seems the lag was caused by the PDO driver. I'm not sure exactly why but ended up using **pg_query** for a single query and **pg_send_query** for batch selects with the asynchronous response which worked really well! Hope this helps others.